# How to properly import React JSX from separate file in Typescript 1.6

Tags: typescript, reactjs, typescript1.6

I have the following app.tsx file working fine loading an App element from a React.Component and a child Worklist element from another React.Component (both classes defined in the same app.tsx file). This is running in Visual Studio with Typescript 1.6 installed (ECMAScript version: ECMAScript 5, JSX compilation: React, Module System: CommonJS).

However, I would like to split these two components into separate files. However, when I uncomment the import of WorkList and remove the class definition for the WorkList component from app.tsx - it fails with an error:

> Error TS2604  JSX element type 'WorkList' does not have any construct
>   or call signatures.

Here is the working app.tsx and the desired worklist.tsx.

```
// app.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
//import * as WorkList from "./worklist";

interface Props {
    foo: string;
}

class WorkList extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <h2>WorkList!{this.props.foo} </h2>
    }
}
class App extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    public render() {
        return <WorkList foo="baz"></WorkList>
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(    
    React.createElement(App, { foo: 'bar' }),
    document.getElementById('app')
);




//worklist.tsx
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
    foo: string;
}

class WorkList extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <h2>WorkList!{this.props.foo} </h2>
    }
}

<WorkList foo="bar" />
```

What is the proper way to import a child JSX with Typescript 1.6?

Here is the working code with the correct answer applied:

```
// app.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM  from "react-dom";
import WorkList from "./worklist";

interface Props {
    foo: string;
}

class App extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    public render() {
        return <WorkList foo="baz"></WorkList>
    }
}       
ReactDOM.render(

    React.createElement(App, { foo: 'bar' }),
    document.getElementById('app')
);

//worklist.tsx
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
    foo: string;
}

export default class WorkList extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <h2>WorkList!{this.props.foo} </h2>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect, that you need to properly export `WorkList` class in the `worklist.tsx` file, e.g. as default export:

```
export default class WorkList extend React.Component<Props, {}>
```

and then import it in `app.tsx`:

```
import WorkList from "worklist"
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect!  This worked!  I tried so many combinations similar to your answer, but not this exact combination.  Thank you!!