# Cannot import React JSX from separate file while using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs, jsx

The issue is similar to [How to properly import React JSX from separate file in Typescript 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456231/how-to-properly-import-react-jsx-from-separate-file-in-typescript-1-6).

It works fine when all the code is in a single file. But when I put the component to a different file and try to import, typescript compiler gives error.

The code looks fine.

Error I get is

> JSX element type 'Hello' does not have any construct or call signatures.

**app.tsx**

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import React = require('react');
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import $ = require('jquery');
import Hello = require('./components/Hello');

$(()=>{
    ReactDOM.render(<Hello name="Tom" />,document.body);
});
```

**components/Hello.tsx**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import React = require('react');

export default class Hello extends React.Component<any,any>{
    render(){
        return <div className="hello">Hello {this.props.name} !</div>;
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrote these lines

```
export default class Hello ...
/* and */    
import Hello = require('./components/Hello');
```

Then you need to write this to consume it:

```
<Hello.Hello name="Tom" />
```

You could instead write this, to change the module to export the class as its top-level object:

```
class Hello ...
export = Hello
```

*or* you could import the `Hello` export from the module with a destructuring:

```
import { Hello } from './components/Hello';
```

*or* you could import the *default* export from the module:

```
import Hello from './components/Hello';
```